# Icon not showing properly on Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, instagram

I am using new Instagram Plugin (which works without API) to show contents related to Instagram account, all is working well with the plugin except that plugin doesnt show content related icons such as `cards`, `videos` etc

Code doesnt add icons related to contents but i not noticed that html code generated by plugin add's CSS classes to anchor element as `instagram-video`, `instagram-image`, `instagram-sidecar`.

based on this i though to use CSS feature to detect css of element such as `.instagram_gallery > a[class*="instagram-video"]`  and add relevent css to show  video icon if anchor element has video class and so.

my code is not showing icon properly as as it can be seen in [codepen example](https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/LYGrKwr)

Code sample

```js
(function($){
            $(window).on('load', function(){
                $.instagramFeed({
                    'username': 'instagram',
                    'container': "#instafeed",
                    'display_profile': false,
                    'display_biography': false,
                    'display_gallery': true,
                    'callback': null,
                    'styling': true,
                    'items': 16,
                    'items_per_row': 4,
                    'margin': 1
                }); 
            });
        })(jQuery);
```

```css
@media (max-width:768px)
    {
    .instagram_gallery > a {
    width: 50% !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
.instagram_gallery > a > img {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 15px;
}
    }

    @media (max-width:500px)
    {
    .instagram_gallery > a {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
.instagram_gallery > a > img {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 15px;
}
    }
.instagram_gallery > a
    {
   
    }
.instagram_gallery > a[class*="instagram-video"] {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  background-image:url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/860/860832.svg')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.sowecms.com/demos/jquery.instagramFeed/jquery.instagramFeed.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container-fluid section-80">
    <div class="row photos-wrap">
         <div id="instafeed"></div>
     </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this CodePen https://codepen.io/DavidSanek/pen/GRoGVrV. I used pseudo-element `:after` to display your icon.

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
    $.instagramFeed({
      username: "instagram",
      container: "#instafeed",
      display_profile: false,
      display_biography: false,
      display_gallery: true,
      callback: null,
      styling: true,
      items: 16,
      items_per_row: 4,
      margin: 1
    });
  });
```

```css
.instagram_gallery {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.instagram_gallery a {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.instagram_gallery img {
  width: 100%!important;
  margin: 0!important;
}

.instagram_gallery .instagram-video:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/860/860832.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.sowecms.com/demos/jquery.instagramFeed/jquery.instagramFeed.min.js"></script>

<div id="instafeed"></div>
```

Comment: I cant see video icon as second items is a video and it show show video icon. i cant see it in your codepen example

Comment: Although I can see it clearly, I've made some changes. Can you please try it again?

Comment: now i can see it now not sure why it was not showing before.. can you add the code snippet also in your solution for clarity. also changing display as flex has broken teh mobility as it should show only two column on small screen. I will fix that just wanted to share so that solution is complete..